# exc_bad_instruction

Tags: json, multithreading, swift

```
func setlLabels(weatherData: NSData) {
    var jsonError: NSError?   
    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as! NSDictionary
    // ...
}
```

after building in line "let json..." there is an error like "thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)"

I think that's a problem related with NSDicitionary, but I don't know how to solve this.

[Screenshot with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrGTK.png)

Comment: You'll have to give us more information than that. Is there a stack trace? It should appear in the debug window down below. That's generally where you'll find some hint as to what actually went wrong. If you can't find that, try setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code leading up to that line to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused when an unexpected thing happens in your app and the app crashes. To fix this, there is some variable that is not supposed to be nil and you force unwrapped it. (!) Here is what a fixed version would look like:

```
func setlLabels(weatherData: NSData) {
    var jsonError: NSError?   
    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as? NSDictionary
    // ...
}
```

As you see, when you remove the `!` after `as` and replace it with `?` it will not crash.